# Android Custom Observer

Tags: android, observers

I looked for the Observer and Observable classes (interface) but I need to create something of more generic.

For example if I would build an observable Paint class I should override many methods.. I don't want this.

I thought maybe is possible to create a custom observer that hold all the methods result of the class to observe and after a `isChanged()` calling return the status (`true` or `false`) comparing the older values with the current values.

The following code method can be used to retrieve all methods inside a generic class:

```
// Found on http://stackoverflow.com/
public static Method[] getAccessibleMethods(Class clazz) {
    List<Method> result = new ArrayList<Method>();
    while (clazz != null) {
        for (Method method : clazz.getDeclaredMethods()) {
            int modifiers = method.getModifiers();
            if (Modifier.isPublic(modifiers) || Modifier.isProtected(modifiers)) {
                result.add(method);
            }
        }
        clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
    }
    return result.toArray(new Method[result.size()]);
}
```

Once we have the methods listed we can call each method and store the results inside an generic array.
When we need to check for some changes we can refresh all the results and comparing with the olds.

So, the question is: is possible to create this kind of custom observer or there is a valid alternative way (or something already done)?

> it's **obvious** that we can only call the methods with determinated characteristic:
>   - no parameters methods
>   - no methods that return void